# Objects in a Namespace are nullptr After Using the Namespace in a Different Source File

Tags: c++

For some reason, when I attempt to use objects in a namespace that were initialized using a different function in the namespace, the objects are all `nullptr`. In the code, I'm using a namespace called `TextRenderer` in `TextRenderer.h`, and in `main.cpp`, I initialize it by calling `TextRenderer::Init()`. In a different file, `TitleState.h`, I try to render some text using `TextRenderer::RenderString(...)`. In that function, it throws an access violation reading address 0. Does anyone know why this would happen? Here are some code snippets of the affected code:

Main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    GraphicsSystem::Init();
    TextRenderer::Init();
    StateManager::InitStack();
    StateManager::PushState(new TitleState());

    audioHandler = new AudioHandler();
    sound = new Sound("assets/audio/loop.ogg");
    sound->play2d(audioHandler, AudioBuses::MUSIC_BUS, true, 1.25f, 1.0f);

    while(!GraphicsSystem::WindowShouldClose()) {
        GraphicsSystem::BeginningOfFrame();

        StateManager::UpdateCurrentState();
        StateManager::RenderCurrentState();

        GraphicsSystem::EndOfFrame();
        GraphicsSystem::PrintOpenGLErrors();
    }

    TextRenderer::DeInit();
    GraphicsSystem::DeInit();

    return 0;
}
```

TitleState render function:

```
void TitleState::Render() {
    TextRenderer::RenderString(std::string("Title State"), 10, 10, Color(255, 0, 0), 3.0f, 3.0f);
}
```

TextRenderer header:

```
#ifndef TEXTRENDERER_H
#define TEXTRENDERER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Texture.h"
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Vector3.h"
#include "Vector4.h"
#include "Vector2.h"
#include "GraphicsSystem.h"

namespace TextRenderer {
    static unsigned char textVertexAttribs[] = {
        3, 4, 2
    };

    static struct TextVertex {
        Vector3 pos;
        Vector4 color;
        Vector2 texCoord;
        TextVertex(float x, float y, float z, float r, float g, float b, float a, float u, float v) : pos(x, y, z), color(r, g, b, a), texCoord(u, v) {}
    };

    static Mesh* textMesh;
    static int fontWidths[256];
    static Texture* fontAtlas;
    static std::vector<TextVertex> vertices;
    static Shader* textShader;

    static void Init() {
        printf("Init Text Renderer\n");
        
        std::ifstream fontDataFile;
        std::stringstream fontDataStream;
        std::string fontDataString;
        fontDataFile.open("assets/fonts/font.csv");
        fontDataStream << fontDataFile.rdbuf();
        fontDataFile.close();
        fontDataString = fontDataStream.str();

        for(int i = 0; i < fontDataString.length() - 5; i++) {
            if(fontDataString.substr(i, 5) == "Char ") {
                i += 5;
                int j = 0;
                while(fontDataString.substr(i + j, 1) != " ") {
                    j++;
                }
                std::string charNum = fontDataString.substr(i, j);
                i += j;
                if(fontDataString.substr(i, 12) == " Base Width,") {
                    i += 12;
                    j = 0;
                    while(fontDataString.substr(i + j, 1) != "\n") {
                        j++;
                    }
                    std::string widthNum = fontDataString.substr(i, j);
                    i += j;
                    fontWidths[std::stoi(charNum)] = std::stoi(widthNum);
                }
            }
        }

        textMesh = new Mesh(textVertexAttribs, sizeof(textVertexAttribs));

        fontAtlas = new Texture();
        fontAtlas->LoadFromFile("assets/fonts/font.png");

        textShader = new Shader("assets/shaders/vertexShaderHUD.glsl", "assets/shaders/fragmentShaderHUD.glsl");
    
        printf("Mesh isn't nullptr: %d\n", (textMesh != nullptr));
        printf("Shader isn't nullptr: %d\n", (textShader != nullptr));
        printf("Texture isn't nullptr: %d\n", (fontAtlas != nullptr));
    }

    static void RenderString(std::string s, float x, float y, Color col, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
        //Clear the vertices vector
        vertices.clear();

        int x2 = 0;

        //Create the vertices for the string
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int c = s.at(i) - 32;

            float u = (float)((c % 16) * 16) / 256;
            float v = (float)((c / 16) * 16) / 256;
            float u2 = (float)(((c % 16) * 16) + 16) / 256;
            float v2 = (float)(((c / 16) * 16) + 16) / 256;

            vertices.push_back(TextVertex(x + x2, y, 0.0f, col.rFloat(), col.gFloat(), col.bFloat(), col.aFloat(), u, v));
            vertices.push_back(TextVertex(x + x2, y + (16 * scaleY), 0.0f, col.rFloat(), col.gFloat(), col.bFloat(), col.aFloat(), u, v2));
            vertices.push_back(TextVertex((x + (16 * scaleX)) + x2, y + (16 * scaleY), 0.0f, col.rFloat(), col.gFloat(), col.bFloat(), col.aFloat(), u2, v2));
            vertices.push_back(TextVertex(x + x2, y, 0.0f, col.rFloat(), col.gFloat(), col.bFloat(), col.aFloat(), u, v));
            vertices.push_back(TextVertex((x + (16 * scaleX)) + x2, y + (16 * scaleY), 0.0f, col.rFloat(), col.gFloat(), col.bFloat(), col.aFloat(), u2, v2));
            vertices.push_back(TextVertex((x + (16 * scaleX)) + x2, y, 0.0f, col.rFloat(), col.gFloat(), col.bFloat(), col.aFloat(), u2, v));
            x2 += fontWidths[c] * scaleX;
        }

        printf("Mesh isn't nullptr: %d\n", (textMesh != nullptr));
        printf("Shader isn't nullptr: %d\n", (textShader != nullptr));
        printf("Texture isn't nullptr: %d\n", (fontAtlas != nullptr));
        textMesh->SetVertexDataDynamic((float*)&vertices[0], vertices.size() * sizeof(float));

        fontAtlas->BindToTexUnit(0);

        textShader->Use();
        textShader->SetMat4("model", glm::mat4(1.0f));
        textShader->SetMat4("proj", GraphicsSystem::GetOrthoMatrix());
        textShader->SetInt("tex", 0);

        //Draw the text string
        textMesh->Draw();
    }

    static void DeInit() {
        printf("De-init Text Renderer\n");
        delete fontAtlas;
        delete textMesh;
        delete textShader;
    }
};

#endif
```

StateManager:

```
#ifndef STATEMANAGER_H
#define STATEMANAGER_H

#include <vector>
#include "GameState.h"
#include "TitleState.h"

namespace StateManager {
    static std::vector<GameState*>* stateStack;
    static bool deleteCurrentState = false;

    static void InitStack() {
        stateStack = new std::vector<GameState*>();
    }

    static void PushState(GameState* gameState) {
        stateStack->push_back(gameState);
    }

    static void PopState() {
        stateStack->at(stateStack->size() - 1)->DeInit();
        stateStack->pop_back();
    }

    static GameState* GetCurrentState() {
        return stateStack->at(stateStack->size() - 1);
    }

    static void UpdateCurrentState() {
        if(deleteCurrentState) {
            deleteCurrentState = false;
            PopState();
        }
        stateStack->at(stateStack->size() - 1)->Update();
    }

    static void RenderCurrentState() {
        stateStack->at(stateStack->size() - 1)->Render();
    }

    static void DisposeAll() {
        for(int i = stateStack->size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            stateStack->at(i)->DeInit();
            stateStack->pop_back();
        }
    }

    static void MarkDeleteCurrState() {
        deleteCurrentState = true;
    }

    static void CancelDeleteCurrState() {
        deleteCurrentState = false;
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: When you declare variables `static` in a header file, then any source file that includes this header will get its own _private_ version of those variables.  That's what `static` provides.  If you wish to expose a variable via a header then declare it `extern` instead and then define it in one source file only.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. Thank you very much! I was able to fix the issue!